# Service binding chain

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

I'm facing a new problem in my application where I have three different Android services.

- **LibService**: this is a service exposed from a library I'm using which connects to BLE sensors and allows the Android device to receive data from them.
- **ConnectionService**: this is a service I've created in a library module of my application which binds to the **LibService** and is in charge of mantain the connections to the BLE sensors.
- **TaskService**: this service, created in my application module, is in charge of compute different tasks using the data received from the sensors. The service binds to the **ConnectionService** in order to receive the data.

The issue I'm facing is how to synchronize the binding chain of these three services. When I bind to the TaskService this in turn binds to the ConnectionService which in turn binds to the LibService. Almost always the first service connection, the one between the TaskService and the ConnectionService, is resolved before the one between the ConnectionService and the LibService. As a result when I use the ConnectionService binder in the TaskService I get a NullPointerException because the ConnectionService does not have the LibService binder yet.

I tryed to use a lock to prevent the ConnectionService to return the binder before a LibService binder has been retrieved but this causes the application to block since the service connection is executed on the main thread preventing it to resolve the second service connection.

Which is the right way to solve the issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of architecture is a bit difficult in Android. My suggestion would be that you have an additional "ready" notification message, that is sent by each `Service` to its bound client **after** it has successfully established its own binding and other resources. You could do this by using a broadcast `Intent` from the `Service` back to its client(s), or you could use 2-way (callback) communication, depending on what communications methods you already have implemented between your `Service`(s) and their clients.

The "ready notification" should be sent after a client binds and until the client receives the "ready notification" it needs to "wait" (this can be done by showing a progress notification or progress dialog or an "initializing..." dialog or an animation or whatever to keep the user occupied.

Comment: +1; Hi @David Wasser , thanks for your reply. That is how I got around the problem right now. I'm using MutableLiveData to let service clients know when it is ready to work. I'll wait to see if other solutions come otherwise I will accept your